# Count rows in database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried using this to access the database:

```
return $db->execute('SELECT `id` FROM `main_games` WHERE `id`=?', array($this->getSubdomain));
```

I am not sure if that worked, as it doesn't even comes up with anything. I have checked that the data should exist but my function always comes up false. Do I have to do another command to return the number of rows?

Comment: sounds like you haven't made a connection to the db first.  why not verify that first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do. But to get the number of rows in a table, say `my_table`, you can do this in SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table
```

Comment: +1 but i would always use `count(1)` instead. it's faster.

Comment: There's no difference between `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(any_constant)`

Comment: @sgroves that is a fallacy -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1

Comment: Tjanks a ton.. That worked for me.